# Angular6 принимает пустой объект {} вместо blob

Tags: spring, angular, angular6

Spring Boot отправляет в потоке данные (excel файл) для клиента:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/excel")
public void exportExcel(@RequestBody List<EventExportParam> cols, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = exportService.getEventExportExcel(cols);
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=events.xls");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    workbook.close();
}
```

Код на сервера рабочий, проблема именно на стороне клиента.
Код клиента:

```
  downloadExcel() {
    this.eventService.exportExcel(this.exportCols).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  }
```

eventService:

```
public exportExcel(exportCols: string[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:9080/export/excel', exportCols, {responseType: 'blob'});
  }
```

На выходе получаю { } объект

Comment: если в консоли браузера сделать `JSON.stringify(new Blob())` - то также получите `{}`, зачем вы стрингифаете блоб?

Comment: Вы правы, все получилось. Спасибо :)